# Create a virtual directory for file IO common dialogs from file paths

Tags: file, clr, directory, archive

I've got an archive containing various files. Would there be a method to list out these files in directories (as dictated by their relative paths) in a common dialog (or a custom dialog for that matter) without having to extract the files or create any directory structure on the file system ? The archive reading code is at my disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to warn you it's not going to be easy.  But you can get a head start by checking out this CodeProject article.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CustomizeFileDialog.aspx

Comment: Too much hassle for my purpose - I guess I'll go write a custom dialog with a listview. Regardless, you have my thanks.

Comment: @shadeMe, I agree.  The common dialogs come from fairly ancient legacy codebase, and not much has been done to make them more extensible from a .NET perspective.  Maybe someone will write an open source library for the .NET community...!